# Make Iframed video auto start in android browser

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a webpage that has an Iframe that has a source that contains a flash video embedded in it.

If I open it on a android phone the video does not auto start. I have to tap to start the video.

I need to make it autostart. Does anyone know how I can do it. I have no control over the original source of the iframe.

Can anyone help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.tvguide.co.uk/tv-stream/?ch=bbc+1" width="1009" height="566">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

If you open this in a browser the video will play. However on an adroid device you have to hit play.

I want it to automatically play.

Comment: I'm voting to close because... **1)** This is not a programming question, is it? **2)** No link to check the problem in action. **3)** Unbelievable that the Android browser can now display Flash Player content (is it default Chrome or some other app)?

Comment: Well I think it is. I thought possibly Java script would be able to some how start it. However, I have not really used it before so do not know what is available.

I have added some code to show the issue.

Comment: In this case you might just have to accept that Android OS won't let the video autoplay. Also note that BBC stream you linked only works for UK connections. Sometimes I use a tool to appear like I'm a USA connection (thereby watching US only content on sites). I forgot to disable that & your link said "stream not available". Otherwise it works fine (I am in the UK anyways). Just letting you know...